# Using refresh access token gives "Request failed: unauthorized (401)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I am working at google calendar api.

Below is the code used to create a calendar

```
if([self.auth shouldRefreshAccessToken]) {
    self.auth.accessToken=self.auth.refreshToken;
}

NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?key=%@&access_token=%@",kGoogleClientID,self.auth.accessToken];

 NSDictionary *params = @{@"summary":@"1233"};

[manager POST:strURL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [operation responseString]);
    NSDictionary *dict =(NSDictionary*)responseObject;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:KDefaultCalendarID];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    //        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    //        UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Request failed due to server error. Please try after some time." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    //        [alertView show];
}];
```

Issue is when refresh token is used, I am getting "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" 
(REFRESH TOKEN IS USED AS USER SHOULD NOT NEED TO LOGIN EVERY TIME)

For normal access token(which is not expired) which is retrieved after user authorizes app 1st time, it works fine.

Below is the run time url which works only till refreshed access token is not used.

Actual URL : https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?key=1080844328725-t8jo4s3cpqtg9orcp63lkujh1dvsqugq.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_token=1/x4c8cfLrfYamVgkBqSsi85N34wX7O_IxFutis08BGaN90RDknAdJa_sgfheVM0X

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) setNewAccessToken {
NSString *clientID=kGoogleClientID;
NSString *clientSecret=kGoogleClientSecret;
NSString *strRefreshToken;

if([self.auth shouldRefreshAccessToken]) {
    strRefreshToken=self.auth.refreshToken;

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"client_secret=%@&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=%@&client_id=%@",clientSecret,strRefreshToken,clientID];
    NSLog(@"%@",post);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *con = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [con start];
 }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// The request is complete and data has been received
// You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
NSString *responseJSON;

// This flag indicates whether the response was received after an API call and out of the
// following cases.

// Convert the received data in NSString format.
responseJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)_receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *dictJsonNotification =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: nil];
NSLog(@"dictJsonNotification %@",dictJsonNotification);

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dictJsonNotification objectForKey:@"access_token"] forKey:KDefaultGmailAccessToken];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[self createCalendar1];
```

}

and then use the saved access token for queries

Comment: Some explanatory text to go with the code in the answer: You can't refresh the access token by presenting the refresh token to the API. You need to get a new access token by presenting the refresh token to the token endpoint `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` in a request that is called a `refresh grant`.